# in F#, is there a way to scan several arrays at the same time and also access the previous element from one of the array?

Tags: f#

I am trying to replicate the following python code:

```
a = (list1 != 0) & (list3.shift() < list2) & (list3 >= list2)
```

so what I need is a function that does something like this pseudo code:

```
(list1, list2, list3)
|||> Array.?? (fun l1, l2, l3, l3previous -> l1 <> 0 && l3previous < l2 && l3 >= l2)
```

this doesn't exist as is, so my question is how can I combine the existing Array functions to make this knowing that speed is important since it has to scan a lot of data in real-time.
(bonus: I need the list of index where the output is true)

I was thinking I could do a pass with zip, and build tuples and then do a map to process the result, but this is certainly not going to be very fast is there a faster way to do this? there is over a million rows and this is going to allocate one tuple per row, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually compare lists in F# just as well as in Python:

```
let list1 = [1;2;3]
let list2 = [4;5]
let a = list1 < list2  // true
```

I'm not sure what `.shift()` does (my local Python 3.7.0 claims it's not a thing), but judging by your F# pseudocode, I guess it's supposed to remove the first element? If so, you can easily do that in F# as well:

```
list2.Tail // Note: this will crash if the list is empty
```

The one thing that I can't figure out is `list1 != 0`. By playing in Python, I have confirmed that it doesn't compare all elements of the list to zero, and it doesn't check that the list has a single element which is zero, and it doesn't check the length. So far as I can see, it always compares list to the number 0, which I guess makes sense in a dynamically typed context, but in F# that would be always `false`, so we can just drop it.

From your F# pseudocode, however, it looks like `list != 0` should be true iff all elements of `list1` are non-zeroes. If so, that can be done in F# with a bit more ceremony:

```
list1 |> List.forall ((<>) 0)
```

And so, assembling it all together, the F# equivalent (with the caveats described above) would be:

```
let a = (list1 |> List.forall ((<>) 0)) && list3.Tail < list2 && list3 >= list2
```

This will have the exact same memory and computation complexities as the Python code. That is, it will traverse `list1` once, and it will traverse `list3` and `list2` in parallel, but twice (once for `<` comparison and once for `>=`), and it will not allocate any intermediate lists.

Answer (score 2):

No combination of existing array functions is going to be as fast as a purpose-built function, so if speed is of more concern than readability, as you seem to suggest, something like this should be preferable:

```
let f (l1 : int array) (l2 : int array) (l3 : int array) = 
    let rec loop i l3prev = 
        if i >= Array.length l1 then 
            true
        else if l1.[i] <> 0 && l3prev < l2.[i] && l3.[i] >= l2.[i] then 
            loop (i + 1) l3.[i]
        else
            false

    loop 0 0
```

This assumes the arrays are of equal length, but if they're not you just need to add bounds-checking to the first `if` condition.